# Issue with EF LINQ query in .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

I have upgraded my web app to NET Core 3 and some EF LINQ queries that were returning values correctly in NET Core 2 now are erroring. I have the following code in my OrderManager class:

```
 private TResult GetOrder<TResult>(Func<Order, bool> condition, Func<Order, TResult> selector)
    {
        return _context.Orders
            .Where(x => condition(x))
                .Include(x => x.OrderStocks)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Stock)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.Product)
                            .Select(selector).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public TResult GetOrderById<TResult>(int id, Func<Order, TResult> selector)
    {
        return GetOrder(order => order.Id == id, selector);
    }

    public TResult GetOrderByReference<TResult>(string reference, Func<Order, TResult> selector)
    {
        return GetOrder(x => x.OrderRef == reference, selector);
    }
```

Looks like dotnet 3 doesn't like that .Where statement:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet
>       .Where(o => Invoke(__condition_0, o[Order])
>       )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

Does anyone know how this query could be re-written correctly? I have tried to add AsEnumerable() in  line: return _context.Orders but thats not the fix, I am a bit blocked here as I am not an expert in LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

`GetOrder` needs to take `Expression<Func<Order, bool>>` as `condition` parameter not `Func<Order, bool>`:

```
private TResult GetOrder<TResult>(Expression<Func<Order, bool>> condition, Func<Order, TResult> selector)
```

After changing the parameter you will need to change `Where` clause also:

```
_context.Orders
        .Where(condition)
```

It seems previously your query was executed on client side, see the [breaking changes list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client).

Though it should be fine to have `Func` for `selector` cause it is last statement in the query, but bear in mind that it will fetch all columns into memory and then preform mapping using needed ones.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! indeed I was executed on the client side, I have done some refactoring to the code. After adding the Parameter Expression as you mentioned above,  I have the error in .Where(x => condition(x)), condition errors with "Method name expected"

Comment: @Tofetopo change it to `Where(condition)`, see he update.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the help and pointing me to those breaking changes list! they'll be useful in the future as I'm sure more queries will be broken :)

Comment: @Tofetopo was glad to help!